# Does Saudi Arabia really control the Chechen terrorist groups?

Tags: terrorism, russian-federation

According to the article linked below, a Saudi prince told Vladimir Putin that he can guarantee the safety of the Winter Olympics in 2014 in Russia if some things will be done by Russia. Does Saudi Arabia control the Chechen terrorist groups?

Here is the article:
[Putin Orders Massive Strike Against Saudi Arabia If West Attacks Syria](http://www.eutimes.net/2013/08/putin-orders-massive-strike-against-saudi-arabia-if-west-attacks-syria/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is pretty much common knowledge in Russia that the Chechen terrorists are financed from Saudi Arabia and Qatar (the same sources which finance the rebellion in Syria).

Several notable terrorists killed in Chechen Republic came from Saudi Arabia, such as [Ibn al-Khattab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_al-Khattab).

In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=192pbHU_uZo), popular Russian observer and blogger aka "El-Murid" explains his point of view that the Second Chechen war was won by Russia only after they killed the key Arab figures such as the mentioned Khattab, through whom the money were distributed.

Once they were killed, the warlords sent their own emissaries to Saudi Arabia and Qatar, but their unity was lost because there was no longer single money distribution center.

Note, it is another well known fact that rebel leader [Yandarbiyev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yandarbiyev) was killed by Russian secret services in Qatar.

According some rumors (El Murid also says this), Qatar currently stopped financing terrorists due to dynastic succession, and as such, Saudi Arabia remains the main source.

Comment: Do you have more authoritative cites than "common knowledge" and a random blogger?

Comment: @DVK he is not just a blogger, he wrote several books on the topic. I choose this video because it is most up-to-date, created several days before now.

Comment: Wahhabism should be mentioned here. Common view in Russia that Saudis push wahhabism into Chechnya in 90-th and that worked - it became main reason of all further calamities. This link describe some details: http://www.weeklystandard.com/blogs/boston-horrors-and-wahhabism-chechnya_719097.html

Comment: @Anixx, I appreciate your informative answer. Well done, dear mate.